# freeglut installation from sources - MinGW

Tags: c, installation, mingw, freeglut

I'm trying to install freeglut for MinGW on a Windows XP machine.
After downloading the sources (from [here](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download)) I followed [these instructions](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/install.php).

I opened a MinGW shell and typed the following commands:

```
./configure
make all
make install
```

Once done I can't find any freeglut.dll file in the directory. 
I'm new at installing from sources, and I don't know what I'm missing here. I would like to understand why. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the

```
./configure --prefix=/mingw
make
make install
```

to put the .dll file into the specific directory. This way your files won't get "lost" within the MSYS directories. The "--prefix=" can use the "/drivename/localpath" format where 'drivename' is 'c', 'd' etc.

If this doesn't help, try compiling FreeGLUT manually using this howto: http://netsuperbrain.com/blog/posts/freeglut-windows-hopengl-hglut/